# Stopping user drawing by double click? As3

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making this game in flash in which I want the user to draw straight lines (to create an unclosed shape) and I want to stop drawing the lines by double clicking.

My *drawing board* is a movie clip (not the stage).

I've put the double click event listener on the board and also added  the  `doubleClickEnabled = true` to the board.

However, no matter what I do, the board won't recognise my double click.

Answer (score 0):

The *click* event gets triggered when there is some clickable entity at the event location. In other words, by for example, "double clicking" on a "transparent" region in your *"drawing board"*, the associated event handler will not be called.

As a solution to the issue, however, you may utilize the `stage` object, since it occupies the entire display area; thus receives the mouse events anyways. The idea is to let the `stage`'s event handler to inform the drawing-board's counterpart about the event occurrence:

```
board.doubleClickEnabled = true;
board.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, onBoardDBLClick);

stage.doubleClickEnabled = true;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, onStageDBLClick);

function onStageDBLClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("STAGE double clicked.");

    // if the location is inside the "board", then inform the "board" about the event!
    if (board.getBounds(stage).contains(e.stageX, e.stageY)) {
        onBoardDBLClick(e);
    }
}

function onBoardDBLClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("The Double-click logic of the board.");
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't work. I added the double click listener to the stage and it works when I double click the stage outside the board, but not when I double click the board itself.

Comment: @Mich I thought you're interested in only being able to double-click on transparent regions on the "board" to finalize the "drawing!", but since you've announced otherwise, then it's just a matter of reconsideration! Check out the edit made to the post :)

Comment: i suggest a simple click handler with a global **deltaTime** variable to determining which clicks are double. because of declaring a custom maximum delay for two consecutive clicks, (for windows its 500 ms). also it can be done with mouseDown and mouseUp events to reducing event listeners and just using existing listeners (exists for drawing job).